# How do I use the WITH statement in Access?

Tags: t-sql, ms-access

I'm using Access and would like to simplify some of my queries by naming `SELECT` statements. However, I can't use the `WITH` statement for some reason. I have tried running the following simple example to illustrate the problem:

```
WITH T1 AS
(
SELECT * FROM [Transactions]
)
SELECT * FROM T1;
```

Where `Transactions` is a table of dates and amounts. When I run this query I get the following error:

> Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Access doesn't support that syntax. Why do you expect it to work? Either rewrite the query along the lines of `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM [Transactions])` or put the `SELECT * FROM [Transactions]` into its own view/query and reference that.

Comment: @ta.speot.is Why the downvote? I'm sorry I didn't know this wouldn't work, do you have a workaround?

Comment: WITH is a VBA statement, not an Access SQL statement

Comment: @kiks73 I was under the impression it was a `T-SQL` statement (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms175972.aspx) and that that's what Access used..Clearly I was wrong!

Comment: You can use t-sql only if you have an access ADP project, connected with a SQL Server DB

Comment: @kiks73 Ah, right. So what's the name of the "language" that Access uses, for future reference?

Comment: ACCESS uses Access-SQL: http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/introduction-to-access-sql-HA010341468.aspx

Comment: @kiks73: it **is** a SQL statement (defined in the SQL standard) and introduces a concept known as "common table expression". But Access does not support this.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, it is but I thought that he confused it with the VBA WITH

Comment: @kiks73 or a pass through query to a DB that supports `WITH`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have stated in the comments, Access SQL does not support the *with* keyword the same way that TSQL does. You can accomplish close to the same thing though by writing the first query and saving it. The saved query can then be referenced in your Access SQL as though it was a table (similar to creating a view in TSQL).

Others also noted that VBA can use the *with* keyword, but for a different purpose.