# MS Access 2013 - How to perform a SQL Update with id based on MAX date from another table?

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update

First time posting, please forgive my newbieness!

In MS Access 2013, How can I update the Actions table's 'LatestRequest' column with the 'id' from the IncomingRequests table by using only for the latest RequestDate for each Scan Result ID ?

Note that there can be duplicate Scan Result IDs in IncomingRequests, but the date will always be different.

Actions Table:

```
id (primary key) | Scan Result ID | LatestRequest | other-misc-columns...
1                | 123456         | (blank)
2                | 666666         | (blank)
3                | 789789         | (blank)
4                | 888888         | (blank) (this record won't change)
5                | 999222         | 987     (this record won't change)
```

IncomingRequests Table:

```
id (primary key) | RequestDate | Scan Result ID | other-misc-columns...
201              | 5/9/2016    | 123456            
202              | 4/12/2016   | 123456            
203              | 5/7/2016    | 666666
204              | 5/8/2016    | 666666
205              | 5/9/2016    | 789789
```

What I want to see:

Action Table:

```
id (primary key) | Scan Result ID | LatestRequest | other-misc-columns...
1                | 123456         | 201
2                | 666666         | 204
3                | 789789         | 205
4                | 888888         | (blank)
5                | 999222         | 987
```

I've tried creating a subquery for the max date, and updating the Actions table, but run into "Operation must use an updateable query".

```
UPDATE Actions INNER JOIN (SELECT t1.*
FROM 
    IncomingRequests t1 
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT [Scan Result ID],  MAX([DateFromIT]) AS MaxDate 
        FROM IncomingRequests 
        GROUP BY [Scan Result ID]
    ) t2 
        ON t1.[Scan Result ID]=t2.[Scan Result ID] 
            AND t1.[RequestDate]=t2.MaxDate
)  AS ij ON Actions.[Scan Result ID] = ij.[Scan Result ID]
SET LatestRequest = ij.id
```

The alternate version I have (below) checks using the Request table primary key id, and this works, except that I really need it by latest date, not highest id.

```
UPDATE Actions
INNER JOIN IncomingRequests ON Actions.[Scan Result ID] = IncomingRequests.[Scan Result ID]
SET Actions.latestrequest = IncomingRequests.id
WHERE IncomingRequests.id=
(SELECT MAX(IncomingRequests.id)
 FROM IncomingRequests
 WHERE Actions.[Scan Result ID] = IncomingRequests.[Scan Result ID]
 GROUP BY IncomingRequests.[Scan Result ID] );
```

I've ran into many dead ends trying to follow other answers from this site, or errors in MS Access that others didn't seem to get. Any assistance appreciated.

Thanks so much! =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually resolved by creating a Sub module in VBA to do the following:

- DROP a temp table.
- Perform a SELECT with the MAX date into a temp table.
- Perform an UPDATE with an INNER JOIN to the temp table.
- DROP the temp table.

Ugly, but it's the only way I could get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if this solved your problem

```
update Actions set Actions.LatestRequest = t2.id
from Actions
inner  join (select id,ScanResultID from IncomingRequests where RequestDate
in (select MAX(RequestDate) from IncomingRequests group by ScanResultID))
t2 on Actions.ScanResultID = t2.ScanResultID
```

Comment: Thanks for the statement. I received an 'Invalid SQL statement' error - it is expecting delete/insert/procedure/select/update. According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24970777/how-do-i-use-the-with-statement-in-access Access doesn't support that statement

Comment: Thanks for the edited answer. Unfortunately it gave a "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 't2.id from Ac..... etc'
  
I removed the 'from Actions' line and put the 'set Actions.LatestRequest = t2.id' AFTER the last line, and that seemed to have at least been syntactically correct.

However, the inner most SELECT MAX() statement disassociates the dates from the ids, and there are duplicate dates. Therefor the outer SELECT statement only has dates to work with, and the query doesn't do what it's supposed to.

Comment: I altered to add back on the prior correct SELECT query, but this in turn made it non-updateable.